# Functional equation $f(f(x)+3y)=12x + f(f(y)-x)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

I found this problem on a French exchange forum :

> Find all the $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f(f(x)+3y)=12x + f(f(y)-x)$

In fact I solved the problem when $f$ is supposed to be continuous. Then it can be shown that $f(x)=3x+\lambda$ for some real constant $\lambda$.

What about the general case, when we do not suppose $f$ to be continuous?

Comment: I modifed the equation, sorry !

Comment: Here, I give some hints. First, prove a function that satisfies the condition must be surjective. Second, use the surjectivity to show it's also injective. Finally, conclude that it has the form $ 3x+c $ for some constant $ c $. If necessary, I'll post my solution.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to see that such a function will be surjective. For the sake of proving injectivity, assume $f(a)=f(b)$ and set $n$ so that $f(n)=a+b$.  Then $$f(f(a)+3n)=12a+f(f(n)-a)=12a+f(b)$$ and $$f(f(b)+3n)=12b+f(f(n)-b)=12b+f(a)$$ so $a=b$, proving that the function is bijective. Then if we substitute $x=0$, we see that $f(3y+f(0))=f(f(y))$ which by injectivity, means that $f(y)=3y+c$ for some constant $ c=f(0)$.

Comment: Why must $f$ be surjective?

Comment: @EricWofsey Substitute $(x,y)=(\frac{f(0)-x}{12}, -\frac{f(\frac{f(0)-x}{12})}{3})$ and it should become obvious